# This page is missing a HtmlHead control which is required for the CSS stylesheetlink that is being added. Please add <head runat="server" />

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

This page is missing a `HtmlHead` control which is required for the CSS
 stylesheetlink that is being added. Please add `<head runat="server" />`.
 i have given `runat="server"` but issue does not resolve what is issue how it will be resolved.

i get this error after providinf `runat=server`

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: This page is missing a HtmlHead control which is required for the CSS stylesheet link that is being added. Please add "server">.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[NotSupportedException: This page is missing a HtmlHead control which is required for the CSS stylesheet link that is being added. Please add "server">.]
   AjaxControlToolkit.ScriptObjectBuilder.RegisterCssReferences(Control control) +249
   AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderControlBase.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +135
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +77
```

Comment: can you show the markup?

Comment: i am using master pages and .net 4.0 with VS 2010

Comment: Have you ever looked into the documentation for `HtmlHead`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlhead.aspx

Comment: i removed head tag from content pages and issue resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i removed head tag from content pages and issue resolve